# java xgettext extract keys inside quoted text

Tags: java, internationalization, extract, gettext, double-quotes

I use Apache Velocity as template manager, inside HTMLs files I have calls to gettext, like in the following piece of code:

```
<img alt="$i18n.tr("Some Text")" title="$i18n.tr("Some Text")" src="http://example.com.blah.jpg"/>
```

Anyone knows a way to extract "Some Text"  despite the quotes surrounding the method, some keywords modifiers or something like that?

PD: I'm using --language=Java option, force by the gettext maven plugin

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try change double quotes to single one:

```
title="$i18n.tr('Some Text')"
```

Velocity should be fine with this.

Comment: That's a valid Velocity syntax, my problem is with that approach the maven gettext plugin (extracting as Java code) will not extract Some Text, because of the single quotes surrounding the text,  it must use double quotes to be extracted